# How to recover private key of an existing one

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, private-key

I'm getting error while updating my mac OS to High sierra 10.13.2 so, I have installed fresh OS. And now I lost my private key, also I have  downloaded my Distribution certificate from apple.developer account but, It showing error of Missing Private key..

I Have done tried many link/blogs where other saying revoke your certificate & create new one to upload app. I tried to follow instruction and created another certificate from XCode, now it showing revoke the certificate error in XCode.

I have Following doubts which i mentioned below ..

1.Is there is any way to recover my private keys?(I'm having old distribution certificate)

2.If I revoked my distribution certificate, but I have  uploaded two apps by using those certificate so,Those app will affect by this setp?

3.If i created new Certificate then can i upload the new version of the existing app

please help me i Forgot Live applications private key and now I need to upload a new version of existing app any help will be very appreciable.

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't recover the lost key. Create a new key and add it to your keychain. Then create a new certificate with the new key. Create updated provisioning profiles with the new certificate. Use the new provisioning profiles to build and submit app updates.

None of this will affect your existing apps already in the App Store.

Comment: someone told if revoke means, you can't upload the new version for the existing app, new app need to upload

Comment: Not true. Certificates expire once a year anyway so every developer has to create a new certificate every year and none of that has ever prevented someone from submitting an app update.

Comment: my account is not enterprise account,this will applicable for my acccount?

Comment: I'm not using an enterprise account either. I've created new certificates many times over the past 9+ years with no issues.

Comment: As of now i clear by your answer new certificate will not affect my existing app.Final solution for my problem is to create new Distribution certificate from OS Updated system to update a new version of the existing app

Comment: can i use the automatically created certificate by Xcode

Comment: I don't see why not. Use Xcode to updated everything.

Comment: Thanks rmaddy.. but i had another issue when uploading "No architectures in the binary. Lipo failed to detect any architectures in the bundle executable"

Comment: That's a completely separate issue unrelated to this one. If this answer solved your original question, you can indicate this by clicking the checkmark next to the answer. Then you can post a new question with all relevant details about your new issue.